# How do I set start and end times for an embedded youtube video buried in a playlist parameter?

Tags: html, api, youtube, url-parameters

I want to embed a custom YouTube playlist made up of only clips of videos using HTML. I know how to modify the first video in the playlist using the parameters listed on Google's developer website (developers[dot]google[dot]com/youtube/player_parameters), but I don't know how to modify the rest of the videos in the playlist queue.

Things I Would Fix:

1) I would only show 30 seconds of the second video (YouTube ID 4A6Bu96ALOw) in the playlist, starting at 21 seconds. 
2) I would also command the player to auto-select the "English - Worry About Yourself" closed captions.

My current code:

http://www.youtube.com/v/Bpu0TIXzI1w?version=3&start=52&end=127&autoplay=1&hl=en_US&rel=0&loop=0&playlist=IQIgy6-PS0A,RwlhUcSGqgs,4A6Bu96ALOw

Hypothesized solution: It must have something to do with creating arrays within the "playlist" parameter

Here is a link to the rest of my research: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1O_ZBzqTe3fpVQ8Lu7r0TBcksTcr95QwaKB_pBpfpKnE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ever find a solution?